# how can I implement this promise scenario in ng2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I implement this promise scenario in ng2?

```
export class MySpecializedClass
{
    myObject;

    constructor(
        private myService: MyService
    )
    {
        this.myObject = new MyObject();
    }

    buildMyObject()
    {
        this.builderMethod1();
        this.builderMethod2();
    }

    builderMethod1()
    {
        this.myService.getData1()
    .then(response => this.myObject.Prop1 = response.Prop1 )
    }

    builderMethod2()
    {
        this.myService.getData2()
    .then(response => this.myObject.Prop2 = response.Prop2 )
    }
}

export class MyConsumerClass
{
    myObect;

    getMyObject()
    {
    this.myObject = new MySpecializedClass().buildMyObject().myObject;
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the following line of code, myObject should not be referenced until builderMethod1() and builderMethod2() are guaranteed complete.

```
MyConsumerClass.getMyObject().myObject
```

I want builderMethod1() and builderMethod2() to run at the same time which is why they aren't chained in a then().  How could I implement this scenario with Promises?  Or would Observables or a different approach provide a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find the async-await syntax a lot more readable than then chaining. Maybe you will too, this is how the same thing can be done using async-await:

```
export class MySpecializedClass
{
    myObject : MyObject;

    constructor(
        private myService: MyService
    )
    {
        this.myObject = new MyObject();
    }

    async buildMyObject()
    {
        const first = this.builderMethod1();
        await this.builderMethod2();
        await first;
        return this.myObject;
    }

    async builderMethod1()
    {
        const response = await this.myService.getData1();
        this.myObject.Prop1 = response.Prop1;
    }

    async builderMethod2()
    {
        const response = await this.myService.getData2();
        this.myObject.Prop2 = response.Prop2;
    }
}

export class MyConsumerClass
{
    myObject;

    async getMyObject()
    {
        this.myObject = await new MySpecializedClass(new MyService()).buildMyObject()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks titian. the original code I provided was a simplification. I followed the async/await pattern you mentioned but buildViewModel is returning an empty object definition.  here's the code:

https://jsbin.com/qejuqihuja/edit?html,js,output

property values are getting set in the code. I can set breakpoints in the code to validate that vm values are getting set.  but by the time the final vm is returned, the vm is an empty object definition. any idea what the gap might be here?

Comment: nevermind I took another look at your example.  async keyword is also used within the child methods thanks

Comment: @user8334943 No problem glad to help, don't forget to mark the answer if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the promise:

```
builderMethod2()
{
   return this.myService.getData2()
           .then(response => {
                 this.myObject.Prop2 = response.Prop2;
                 return response.Prop2;
             })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in both promise and Observable. I would prefer observable as it have more options over promise

**promise**
 In case of promise, you need to return promise/differ. But in your case you are not returning anything and also when you say `.then` it resolves the promise

export class MySpecializedClass
{
    myObject;

```
constructor(
    private myService: MyService
)
{
    this.myObject = new MyObject();
}

buildMyObject()
{
    var diff = differed // find out exact differed object
    return diff.all(this.builderMethod1(), this.builderMethod2());
}

builderMethod1()
{
     return this.myService.getData1()
.then(response => this.myObject.Prop1 = response.Prop1 )
}

builderMethod2()
{
    return this.myService.getData2()
.then(response => this.myObject.Prop2 = response.Prop2 )
}
```

}

export class MyConsumerClass
{
    myObect;

```
getMyObject()
{
 this.myObject = new MySpecializedClass().buildMyObject().then (() => {
   myObject;
 }
}
```

}

**Observable**
In case of observable you can you `Observable.merger`, `Observable.formJoin` etc to join 2 of your observable and subscribe them

Comment: thanks ani. did you mean to say "deferred" instead of "differed"? google didn't return any refs to differed.all() but instead returns results for deferred.all(). however, deferred.all() appears to be part of the $q library.  Is that a jQuery lib or ng lib? sorry I'm not clear on your "differed" reference.  I added the var diff declaration but I get a compiler error.  what ng2 import should I use for this?

Comment: Actually I ment deferred.all() . And yes its part of $q and I am sure you will ger a equivalent in your library or promise. you can also use differ.when(). please explore and i think you will get few options in promise